# how to make sure you have a working DCAP setup

Tags: sgx

I have installed gramine and DCAP using the fifth step:5. Install dependencies for DCAP of link https://gramine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/devel/building.html?highlight=dcap#install-dependencies-for-dcap
my questions are that:
how can I make sure that DCAP is enabled on my server?
how client can verify that his request is executed inside SGX? how can he make sure about it?